# How to outline fonts with a different color?

Tags: windows-7, adobe-photoshop, paint.net, microsoft-paint

I am trying to put letters on an existing image that are outlined in a different color.

Example below.  Note how the letters below have white color, yet the outline is in black.  Directions on how to do that in Paint.NET or Photoshop or MS Paint would be great.  Or is it a specific font that I have to use?

[image]

Comment: Adobe Illustrator has the text outline feature...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an [Outline plugin for Paint.NET](http://paint.net.amihotornot.com.au/Features/Effects/Plugins/Object/Outline/) which you can use:

1. First the image (the text is on a separate layer above; the background is just so it's obvious):

   [image]
2. Then the Outline plugin:

   [image][image]
3. And voila:

   [image]

---

If you don't care about crisp, pixel-y edges of the outline, then you can simply do the following which doesn't need a plugin:

1. Start with the text on a separate layer again:

   [image]
2. Duplicate that layer:

   [image]
3. Blur the lower with a radius of how large your outline should be:

   [image]
   [image]
4. Use the magic wand with a tolerance of 0 % and the flood mode set to global on the empty space around the now-blurred text:

   [image]
   [image]
5. Invert the selection with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>:

   [image]
6. Set your foreground colour back to black and press <kbd>← Backspace</kbd>. This will fill the selection with black. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to deselect again:

   [image]

---

There is a longer method, also without a plugin, but it's slightly messy. It is described [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gt0FctF01x4), but the voice makes it a little hard to bear.

Answer (score 5):

### Photoshop

In Photoshop, to get outlines for any shape, check the layer's *Blending Options…*.

[image]

Here, apply *Stroke*. Don't forget to set the right size:

[image]

And you're done:

[image]

---

### Paint.NET

Paint.NET doesn't do it by default, but it has an [Outline Plugin](http://paint.net.amihotornot.com.au/Features/Effects/Plugins/Object/Outline/) you can use to achieve the same.

[image]

---

### Paint

Paint is too limited in this regard. I wouldn't even try. Maybe your pixel-based drawing skills are good enough – but apart from that it simply doesn't offer that feature.

---

By the way, the specific font you may want to use for image-based memes is *Impact*.